# Flutter Frontend + Kotlin Backend Project Organization

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

Here's what I've done in IntelliJ:

- Created a Kotlin Mobile Library named "backend".
- Create a Flutter project named "frontend".
- Created an empty IntelliJ project and dumped both projects inside.

I am able to build each project individually and run my frontend in an emulator. My goal here is to use Dart `MethodChannels` so that I can have my Kotlin library do all of the heavy lifting + business logic, while Flutter/Dart just render UI. In addition to all of the Gradle- and IntelliJ-related headaches (Kotlin DSL vs Groovy, etc.) I've run into in the past 1.5 days of working on this, I'm doubting this strategy, as I'm having trouble finding good examples or discussion of what I'm trying to accomplish. (I'm aware of the Flutter `platform_channel` example, but that directly integrates the Kotlin into the Android subproject, and I'm trying to completely isolate my frontend from the backend.)

Ideally, both projects would eventually be managed by the same `build.gradle.kts` as subprojects, and properly depend upon each other in an idiomatic Gradle fashion. For the time being, I'm working around this by using the following task in the Android portion of my backend:

```
tasks.register<Copy>("copyAAR") {
    from("$buildDir/outputs/aar")
    into("../frontend/android/app/src/main/libs")
}
```

And then my frontend Android Dart task (in IntelliJ) depends upon `backend:android:assemble` and `backend:android:copyAAR`. (I have not yet successfully included the appropriate debug/release AAR into my Flutter project via Gradle and used it.)

I'd accept answers to any of the following:

- Does my strategy seem reasonable or is there a better way?
- Can someone point me to a concrete example of what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I really like the idea here - Kotlin for business logic and Flutter front-end. Have you figured out a way forward since posting your question?

Comment: Apart from minor updates, haven't had time to work on this outside of my job lately. Was kind of hoping Google would drop Flutter + Kotlin support and solve this for me :)

Comment: Did you get any leads to this..I am trying to achieve same.