# Kotlin for backend + Flutter for the frontend?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to build an android application for image recognition. it's a real time service, so i need to do everything locally. here's the objective:

- extract image frames from input video stream
- detect keypoints and match them with those of the reference images
- find the closest match and return the id/class

My initial approach was to build a CNN model, `VGG-16` architecture, host it as a web service, and then communicate via the Flutter app. but the model turned out to be computationally expensive and the results weren't sufficient enough to balance that out. and yes i totally forgot about the app being real time and thus ruled out this approach.

Then i looked for something more light and came across `ORB` and was able to implement it in Python, thanks to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe-KWKPk9Zc&t=816s) tutorial and was on the right track. i still cannot use it as an API so somehow had to find a way to implement it in Flutter. i could run it using a Python script in the app background and still use Flutter with the help of plugins such as `starflut` or `chaquopy` but this approach works for desktop applications only i think?(as i would eventually need a Python environment to run the script?) or thats what i could gather in my initial research.

OpenCV for Flutter only consists of basic image processing functions and deoesnt go deep into image keypoints detection or image matching algorithms such as `SIFT`, `FAST` or `ORB`. OpenCV for Kotlin, on the other hand has everything i need. I came across this old [blogpost](https://akshikawijesundara.medium.com/object-recognition-with-opencv-on-android-6435277ab285) from 2016 which turned out to be a gem. I tried implementing it, faced a lot of troubles(too many, infact) but finally got my app running. the process was very tedious and being new to mobile dev, i dont think id be able to use Kotlin for the entire project.

so now my plan is to do the Kotlin compatible stuff in Kotlin, basically using Kotlin do the heavy lifting OpenCV work, and do Flutter compatible stuff in Flutter, like the UI and the rest of the functionality of my app. I now know you could do so using `MethodChannels` wherein you could include a Java/Kotlin file and then import and use it in your Flutter application?

I need to know if this approach is viable or has previously been done before, any blogs or tutorials or documentations covering this would be a great head start for me.

also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911548/flutter-frontend-kotlin-backend-project-organization) unanswered question is the closest thing i could find.

Answer (score 0):

after a few more days of looking and experimenting, i finally found [this](https://medium.com/calmexperts/implementing-kotlin-native-code-on-your-flutter-application-b576ab524b41) beautiful blog which helped me do what i needed and im leaving this here for anyone interested.

and it did use `MethodChannels` as i anticipated.